# Is Hackney able to connect to multiple SOCKS5 circuits at a time

Tags: erlang, elixir, socks

I'm using [Hackney](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney) in an Elixir Project where I try to connect to multiple Tor circuits at a time via SOCKS5. I'm making this requests to a site that simply return the IP address in the response body and nothing else.

The problem is that when I make a request via one of the Tor processes and then **immediately** another one via another Tor process, I get the same IP address( so almost cetainly both requests go through the same circuit).

```
 > {:ok, status, headers, c1} = :hackney.request(:get ,url, [], "", [{:proxy, {:socks5, :localhost, 9062}}])
 > :hackney.body(c1) 
 {:ok, "one.ip.add.ress\n"}
 > {:ok, status, headers, c2} = :hackney.request(:get ,url, [], "", [{:proxy, {:socks5, :localhost, 9063}}])
 > :hackney.body(c2) 
 {:ok, "one.ip.add.ress\n"}
```

If I wait about 1 minute and make the same request with the other process first I get his IP for both:

```
 > {:ok, status, headers, c2} = :hackney.request(:get ,url, [], "", [{:proxy, {:socks5, :localhost, 9063}}])
 > :hackney.body(c2)     
 {:ok, "two.ip.add.ress\n"}
 > {:ok, status, headers, c1} = :hackney.request(:get ,url, [], "", [{:proxy, {:socks5, :localhost, 9062}}])
 > :hackney.body(c1)          
 {:ok, "two.ip.add.ress\n"}
```

and if I wait another 1 minute or so I get the IP of the first one for both again.

```
 > {:ok, status, headers, c1} = :hackney.request(:get ,url, [], "", [{:proxy, {:socks5, :localhost, 9062}}])
 > :hackney.body(c1)        
 {:ok, "one.ip.add.ress\n"}
 > {:ok, status, headers, c2} = :hackney.request(:get ,url, [], "", [{:proxy, {:socks5, :localhost, 9063}}])
 > :hackney.body(c2)         
 {:ok, "one.ip.add.ress\n"}
```

If I wait for a longer period both IP's change but again If I make a request through both processes within a short time interval I will get the same IP for both( the IP of the first TOR process I used):

```
 > {:ok, status, headers, c1} = :hackney.request(:get ,url, [], "", [{:proxy, {:socks5, :localhost, 9062}}])
 > :hackney.body(c1)        
 {:ok, "new.ip.add.ress\n"}
 > {:ok, status, headers, c2} = :hackney.request(:get ,url, [], "", [{:proxy, {:socks5, :localhost, 9063}}])
 > :hackney.body(c2)         
 {:ok, "new.ip.add.ress\n"}
```

Is there a way to avoid this in Hackney?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you start the multiple Tor instances with different data dirs.(`--DataDirectory` parameter).